# URL Rewrite a previously rewritten URL - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

OK so... I have the following URL which works on my site:

```
http://my_domain.net/w/mRD3nKkM
```

The rewrite for this in the root of my site is:

```
RewriteRule ^([w])/(\w+)$ res/$1/response.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Simple stuff and works a treat. Now I want to redirect any traffic that hits that URL unencrypted to go over https, like below:

```
https://my_domain.net/w/mRD3nKkM
```

So I put another .htaccess file within the `res/w/` folder conatining the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/response.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my_domain.net/w/$1 [R,L]
```

To my miind this should work, but doesn't.

To be clear, I have the following URL rewrite working:

```
http://my_domain.net/w/mRD3nKkM
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
https://my_domain.net/w/mRD3nKkM
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle `http => https` before doing internal forward stuff. Following should work for you:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^w/.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(w)/(\w+)/?$ res/$1/response.php?id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect. I had to use `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` as I am using an AWS Load Balancer and the protocol used is transmitted in that header.